# AutoHide Progressbar with StyleTriggers

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, triggers, progress-bar

I would like to hide a progressbar in WPF using databinding. Whenever a property is 0, the progressbar should hide: I try the following code

(Info: My current datacontext is a class that holds an integer property 'CurrentIndex')

```
<ProgressBar Minimum="0" Maximum="100" Value="{Binding CurrentIndex, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Visibility="Visible">
    <ProgressBar.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CurrentIndex}" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ProgressBar.Style>
</ProgressBar>
```

What is wrong with this code? Why does the progressbar still show up when the CurrentIndex is 0? (in the model behind, the value of 'CurrentIndex' is 0 by default, when the control is loaded)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DP precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), do not set `Visibility` on the control itself (local value > style).

Comment: Makes perfectly sense now: In fact, if I set the Visibility in the style it works just fine:

Answer (score 1):

Your XAML was almost right!

Define your progressbar as you did:

```
<ProgressBar Minimum="0" 
             Maximum="100" 
             Value="{Binding CurrentIndex, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
             Name="MyAutoHidingProgressBar" />
```

Don't forget to add the `Name` property AND do not set the `Visibility` here.
It will always override what is set in your `Style`.

Then define a `Style` as normal in your `<Window.Resources>`

```
 <Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="ProgressBar" x:Key="MyAutoHidingProgressBarStyle">
       <Style.Triggers>
           <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=MyAutoHidingProgressBar, Path=Value}" Value="0">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"></Setter>
           </DataTrigger>
       </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

What this is basically doing is to check the Value of the progressbar itself, rather than your binding.

As a last step add the Style to your progressbar:

```
Style="{StaticResource MyAutoHidingProgressBarStyle}"
```

Now your `ProgressBar` will auto hide if its `Value` is `0`.
You can also easily add a Trigger to hide it if its full.

Answer (score 0):

Other way to use visibility binding and a converter:

```
<Grid>
<Grid.Resources>
    <App:VisibilityConverter x:Key="VisibilityConverter" />
</Grid.Resources>
<ProgressBar Minimum="0" Maximum="100" Value="{Binding CurrentIndex, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
             Visibility="{Binding CurrentIndex, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}" />
</Grid>
```

The converter code (VisibilityConverter.cs):

```
public class VisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (int)value == 0 ? Visibility.Hidden : Visibility.Visible;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```